# Swift, How to Get Completion Handler working as I Wish?

Tags: swift, firebase, closures, completionhandler

I am fetching user information from Firebase and my goal is to fetch a batch of users and then display them on the screen one at a time in a card stack. To do this i use a completion handler. However my code inside the completion handler runs before the fetch of all users is done.

Thank you for any help.

Here is my code. I want "fetchOneUser()" to run when "fetchAllUsers" is done:

```
fetchAllUsers(completion: { message in
   print(message)
   print("FetchOneUser")
   self.fetchOneUser()
})
```

Here is fetchAllUser function:

```
func fetchAllUsers(completion: @escaping (_ message: String) -> Void){
        //User or advertiser?
        Database.database().reference(withPath: "Advertiser").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.exists(){
                myAdvertiserVar.advertiser = true
                self.currentUserKind = "Advertiser"
                self.otherUserKind = "Users"
            }
            else{
                self.currentUserKind = "Users"
                self.otherUserKind = "Advertiser"
            }

            // Fetch
            let query = self.ref?.child(self.otherUserKind).queryOrdered(byChild: "email")
            query?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
                (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let id = child.key
                    //If Already Accepted, don't fetch
                    Database.database().reference(withPath: self.currentUserKind).child(self.uid).child("Accepted").child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(accepted) in
                        if accepted.exists(){
                            print("\(id) är redan Accepted")
                        }
                        else{
                            if myAdvertiserVar.advertiser == true{
                                let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
                                let username = value?["Username"] as? String
                                let occupation = value?["Occupation"] as? String
                                let age = value?["Age"] as? String
                                let bio = value?["Bio"] as? String
                                let email = value?["email"] as? String
                                let user = User(id: id, username: username, occupation: occupation, age: age, bio: bio, email: email)
                                self.usersArray.append(user)
                            }
                            else{
                                let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
                                let username = value?["Owner"] as? String
                                let occupation = value?["Location"] as? String
                                let age = value?["Rent"] as? String
                                let bio = value?["About"] as? String
                                let email = value?["email"] as? String
                                let user = User(id: id, username: username, occupation: occupation, age: age, bio: bio, email: email)
                                self.usersArray.append(user)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
                print(self.usersArray.count)
                completion("Users list fetched")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: try to create database refrence out of for loop, Database.database().reference connect async to real time database which returns results when for loop finished if this helped please notify me, i could not test because Firebase restricted iranian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DispatchGroup` as the inner calls are asynchronous

```
func fetchAllUsers(completion: @escaping (_ message: String) -> Void){
    //User or advertiser?
    Database.database().reference(withPath: "Advertiser").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists(){
            myAdvertiserVar.advertiser = true
            self.currentUserKind = "Advertiser"
            self.otherUserKind = "Users"
        }
        else{
            self.currentUserKind = "Users"
            self.otherUserKind = "Advertiser"
        }

        // Fetch
        let query = self.ref?.child(self.otherUserKind).queryOrdered(byChild: "email")
        query?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
            (snapshot) in

            let g = DispatchGroup()

            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let id = child.key
                //If Already Accepted, don't fetch

                g.enter()

                Database.database().reference(withPath: self.currentUserKind).child(self.uid).child("Accepted").child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(accepted) in
                    if accepted.exists(){
                        print("\(id) är redan Accepted")
                    }
                    else{
                        if myAdvertiserVar.advertiser == true{
                            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
                            let username = value?["Username"] as? String
                            let occupation = value?["Occupation"] as? String
                            let age = value?["Age"] as? String
                            let bio = value?["Bio"] as? String
                            let email = value?["email"] as? String
                            let user = User(id: id, username: username, occupation: occupation, age: age, bio: bio, email: email)
                            self.usersArray.append(user)
                        }
                        else{
                            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
                            let username = value?["Owner"] as? String
                            let occupation = value?["Location"] as? String
                            let age = value?["Rent"] as? String
                            let bio = value?["About"] as? String
                            let email = value?["email"] as? String
                            let user = User(id: id, username: username, occupation: occupation, age: age, bio: bio, email: email)
                            self.usersArray.append(user)
                        }
                    }

                    g.leave()
                })
            }


            g.notify(queue: .main, execute: {

                print(self.usersArray.count)
                completion("Users list fetched")

            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Firebase documentation:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Firebase use `refrence()` method to get a database refrence for the root of your real time database asynchronous.

this means that result takes more time to fetch than for loop, in this situation your for loop finishes and completion block calls and takes you out of method, then result of your request will return.

your code should look like

```
var firebaseDatabaseRefrence: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   Database.database().reference(withPath: self.currentUserKind)
}

func someMethod() {

  self.firebaseDatabaseRefrence
  .child(self.uid)
  .child("Accepted")
  .child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(accepted) in 

}
```